Insert a very long function using VBA
Heyo, I am trying to use VBA to insert a (very) long formula into a workpage. I keep getting an "Application defined/objeft defined" error.
Hoping there's either a way to make this work or maybe just optimize the formula in general as it is quite silly but I couldn't find a workaround.
Effectively the formula checks every cell for a specific phrase then asks for the value of the cell 2 rows below it.
Dim sFrm As String

 sFrm = "=IF(Invoice_Statement!A20=""Total Amount Due: "",Invoice_Statement!A22,IF(Invoice_Statement!A21=""Total Amount Due: "",Invoice_Statement!A23,IF(Invoice_Statement!A22=""Total Amount Due: "",Invoice_Statement!A24,IF(Invoice_Statement!A23=""Total Amount Due: "",Invoice_Statement!A25,IF(Invoice_Statement!A24=""Total Amount Due: "",Invoice_Statement!A26,IF(Invoice_Statement!A25=""Total Amount Due: "",Invoice_Statement!A27,IF(Invoice_Statement!A26=""Total Amount Due: "",Invoice_Statement!A28," & _
"IF(Invoice_Statement!A27=""Total Amount Due: "",Invoice_Statement!A29,IF(Invoice_Statement!A28=""Total Amount Due: "",Invoice_Statement!A30,IF(Invoice_Statement!A29=""Total Amount Due: "",Invoice_Statement!A31,IF(Invoice_Statement!A30=""Total Amount Due: "",Invoice_Statement!A32,IF(Invoice_Statement!A31=""Total Amount Due: "",Invoice_Statement!A33,IF(Invoice_Statement!A32=""Total Amount Due: "",Invoice_Statement!A34,IF(Invoice_Statement!A33=""Total Amount Due: "",Invoice_Statement!A35,IF(Invoice_Statement!A34=""Total Amount Due: "",Invoice_Statement!A36," & _
"IF(Invoice_Statement!A35=""Total Amount Due: "",Invoice_Statement!A37,IF(Invoice_Statement!A36=""Total Amount Due: "",Invoice_Statement!A38,IF(Invoice_Statement!A37=""Total Amount Due: "",Invoice_Statement!A39,IF(Invoice_Statement!A38=""Total Amount Due: "",Invoice_Statement!A40,IF(Invoice_Statement!A39=""Total Amount Due: "",Invoice_Statement!A41,IF(Invoice_Statement!A40=""Total Amount Due: "",Invoice_Statement!A42,"")))))))))))))))))))))"

            Range("J3").Value = sFrm


=IFERROR(OFFSET(Invoice_Statement!A20,1+MATCH("Total Amount Due: ",Invoice_Statement!A20:A40,0),0),"")

Try Range("J3").Formula2 = sFrm - once you've sorted out your formula with Tim's help.

Answer I came up with to make the function more efficient was
=VLOOKUP(M3&"*",Invoice_Statement!A:D,1,FALSE)

Where M3 contains the first 5 characters of the actual row I was looking for (the first 5 are always the same, the rest varies)
Tim's solution also worked and I'm definitely keeping that in mind if a similar issue comes up
=IFERROR(OFFSET(Invoice_Statement!A20,1+MATCH("Total Amount Due: ",Invoice_Statement!A20:A40,0),0),"") 

